# base64 to S3 multiple images

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I'm currently using the following code to upload a base64 string to AWS S3

```
buf = new Buffer(req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')
var data = {
    Key: String(product._id),
    Body: buf,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    ACL: 'public-read'
};

s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            msg: 'Oops! Something went wrong.' + err
        });
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        var url = "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/" + String(product._id);
        product.image = url;
        product.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'Oops! Something went wrong.' + err
                });


            // Return the product
            res.json({
                success: true,
                product: product
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This works fine for uploading just 1 single image to the AWS S3 platform. We're now making a change to the app which means we want to upload multiple images, so what the server will receive is an array of base64 images. What'd be the best way to have those uploaded to the AWS S3 platform? I was unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using AWS javascript SDK, sadly as you probably know s3 putObject only supports uploading one object per HTTP request.

I would speed up the image uploading by sending multiple requests in parallel using promises.

Example with some untested code:

```
const promises = images.map(img => s3Bucket.putObject({
      Key: img._id,
      Body: new Buffer(img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64'),
      ContentEncoding: 'base64',
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
      ACL: 'public-read'}).promise());

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data); // this should be an array of resolved s3 put object promises now
        // you probably want to update your product model accordingly here, I'm just copying your existing code
        var url = "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/" + String(product._id);
        product.images = url;
        product.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return res.json({
              success: false,
              msg: 'Oops! Something went wrong.' + err
            });
          }
          // Return the product
          return res.json({
            success: true,
            product: product
          });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //handle the error in case one of the promises gets rejected
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            msg: 'Oops! Something went wrong.' + err
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Good start! It does run but then throws an error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` because it'll return the res.json multiple times (one time for every image I guess). Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: Hey, @MatthijsOtterloo I updated the code snippet, try that one instead. I think one of the promises inside Promise.all call was being rejected and the catch block was handling that and returning res.json() result to the next `then` in the promise chain thus executing res.json twice.

Comment: Still having the same issue, catch(err) { process.nextTick(function() { throw err}); }
                                                 ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client